# Using Unity's new Entity Component System

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to ask when to use ECS. My logic is telling me, that I should use it only when I need to control a larger amount of objects. Am I right, or should I use it everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My logic is telling me, that I should use it **only** when I need to
>   control a larger amount of objects.

Not really but it helps when it's used to control many objects. This is not the only or main objective of ECS. See the list reasons why ECS should be used below:

- Performance
- Memory Management
- Build Size

It's not only used when you are working with many objects, it's also used to manage the memory. It reduces the amount of memory required when ECS is used than when the Unity's component system is used. Also, it reduces the build size too. With ECS, you can reduce the build size of your project. ECS makes it possible to use Unity's API as modules, You can decide which modules to include in the build therefore reducing the project size. For example, you can decide to remove the physics system if you don't need it in your project.

Finally, ECS is really important when it comes to building lightwight projects. For example, if you want to build a lightweight game or interactive program that would run on other smaller devices as an Ad, ECS should be used here since it will reduce the size of the Ad, loading time, the memory footprint. You should watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWVU6cFdmr0) video and visit the Unity's [ECS page](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/job-system-ECS) to learn more about it.

**So,when should you use ECS?**

When you need performance, want to conserve memory, reduce the build size of your project or create a lightweight program. Of-course there are many other uses of it. It's still new and we will find out more about it very soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is very helpful.